# Prepare for segue not sending all of the information (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

When trying to pass `String` variables to a new `ViewController`, only one of the variables is being sent. I'm not sure what is going on here, because when I print `object["eventDescription"]`, the console does indeed print the description. Only eventName is being passed to the new view controller.

Sending view controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "detailSegue") {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? EventDetailViewController {
            if let eventIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! FeedCustomCell) {
                var object = self.eventsArray[eventIndex.row]

                destination.nameText = object["eventName"] as! String
                destination.descriptionText = object["eventDescription"] as! String
                print(object["eventDescription"])
```

The destination view controller (EventDetailViewController):

```
class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descLabel: UILabel!

    var descriptionText = String()
    var nameText = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.eventName.text = nameText
        self.descLabel.text = descriptionText
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you will go through the compiler? Those properties you are passing are not matching.

Comment: I edited it, sorry about that Lucas.

Comment: Then, you should be good to go. Delete this post then.

Comment: In a now-deleted answer you reveal more information about what's going wrong. How do you expect us to help you if you don't provide a complete description of your problem? Please edit your question to describe what your app is doing that doesn't meet your needs. Is it failing silently to pass the info to the destination, or something else?

Comment: @LucasHuang unfortunately I'm not good to go.

Comment: @DuncanC It is failing silently in the background. I'm not sure where you are confused, I stated that I'm trying to pass values over to a new view controller and that new view controller is only picking up one of the values.

Comment: Did you try to debug what's going on?

Comment: In the comments on the deleted answer you said "Even with that i'm getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". That is a key piece of information that I would hardly call "failing silently."

Comment: I updated the status of the question to be where I am at now, so that error is no longer irrelevant thus I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting anybody's time, but I had to place constraints onto the description UILabel in the EventDetailController, and then I could see the description.